# Is there a setting in the Windows headers that disables definition of TCHAR-neutral function name macros?

Tags: c++, windows

Let's say I'm implementing a simple wrapper around [ExpandEnvironmentStringsW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265.aspx):

//ExpandNStuff.hpp:

```
#include <string>
namespace WindowsApi
{
    std::wstring ExpandEnvironmentStrings(const std::wstring& source);
}
```

//ExpandNStuff.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "ExpandNStuff.hpp"
#include "Win32Exception.hpp"
namespace WindowsApi
{
    std::wstring ExpandEnvironmentStrings(const std::wstring& source)
    {
        DWORD len;
        std::wstring result;
        len = ::ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(source.c_str(), 0, 0);
        if (len == 0)
        {
            THROW_LAST_WINDOWS_ERROR();
        }
        result.resize(len);
        len = ::ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(source.c_str(), &result[0], len);
        if (len == 0)
        {
            THROW_LAST_WINDOWS_ERROR();
        }
        result.pop_back(); //Get rid of extra null
        return result;
    }
}
```

No big deal -- everything makes sense up to this point. Look what happens when
I add in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ExpandNStuff.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::wstring source(L"Hello World! Windows is in %WINDIR%");
    std::wstring expanded(WindowsApi::ExpandEnvironmentStrings(source));
    std::wcout << expanded << std::endl;
}
```

Surprise! This code will not link. The reason is that in the `ExpandNStuff.cpp`
translation unit, the `windows.h` header defined `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` to
be `ExpandEnvironmentStringsW` using a macro, despite the fact that we tried
to make our implementation distinct by putting it in a namespace. Therefore
the `ExpandNStuff.cpp` translation unit thinks the function is called
`WindowsApi::ExpandEnvironmentStringsW` rather than
`WindowsApi::ExpandEnvironmentStrings`, as the author expects. But the `main.cpp` translation unit does not `#include <windows.h>`, so it's name does not match that in the `ExpandNStuff.cpp` translation unit.

The fix is to add this into `ExpandNStuff.hpp`:

```
#ifdef ExpandEnvironmentStrings
#undef ExpandEnvironmentStrings
#endif
```

However, doing this for every API can be tedious. I'd rather simply be forced into calling the "W" or "A" version of the function explicitly than be bitten by `#define` bugs like this one. Is there a way to turn off the macros?

Comment: I really wish there was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their definitions aren't wrapped in any macro.

```
WINBASEAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
GetVolumeInformationA(
    __in_opt  LPCSTR lpRootPathName,
    __out_ecount_opt(nVolumeNameSize) LPSTR lpVolumeNameBuffer,
    __in      DWORD nVolumeNameSize,
    __out_opt LPDWORD lpVolumeSerialNumber,
    __out_opt LPDWORD lpMaximumComponentLength,
    __out_opt LPDWORD lpFileSystemFlags,
    __out_ecount_opt(nFileSystemNameSize) LPSTR lpFileSystemNameBuffer,
    __in      DWORD nFileSystemNameSize
    );
WINBASEAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
GetVolumeInformationW(
    __in_opt  LPCWSTR lpRootPathName,
    __out_ecount_opt(nVolumeNameSize) LPWSTR lpVolumeNameBuffer,
    __in      DWORD nVolumeNameSize,
    __out_opt LPDWORD lpVolumeSerialNumber,
    __out_opt LPDWORD lpMaximumComponentLength,
    __out_opt LPDWORD lpFileSystemFlags,
    __out_ecount_opt(nFileSystemNameSize) LPWSTR lpFileSystemNameBuffer,
    __in      DWORD nFileSystemNameSize
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetVolumeInformation  GetVolumeInformationW
#else
#define GetVolumeInformation  GetVolumeInformationA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

You can see that there's no handy switch to prevent the #defining of GetVolumeInformation.

EDIT:

Boost has a solution- BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION. They use it for min() and max(). "Use min BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION (a,b); to make an argument-dependent call to min(a,b).".

Comment: Damnit :( +1. Grrrrr. Maybe I should have just read the damn things myself lol. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @Billy: If you know the exact functions that you need, you could just make your own header with their declarations in and not #include windows.h at all.

Answer (score 1):

Those tens of thousands of macros in the Windows header are definitely annoying. The best I could come up with so far is to

1. severely restrict including `<windows.h>`
2. punctually un-define anything that comes up:

   ```
   #include <string>
   #undef ExpandEnvironmentStrings // take off, WinAPI!
   namespace WindowsApi
   {
     std::wstring ExpandEnvironmentStrings(const std::wstring& source);
   }
   ```

But #2 is a last resort, much more can be achieved by strictly sticking to #1.

Comment: @Will, you're a pretending prude!